# How to disable the touch from a raspberry pi screen?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, touchscreen

I am working on a project where an **RFID** reader will read some tags then display some information in a GUI. The user can control the system from the GUI using the *raspberry pi touchscreen*.
The problem is that both the screen and the **RFID** reader use the *spi*. As raspberry has two channels I guess it is possible to connect both.But I don't know how to switch between them.

Currently, the touch driver is installed in the booting file, What methods can I use to enable/disable the screen? and how I can switch between the screen and the reader?

Note:
I tried different methods to disable the screen as   (*touchscreen = 1*) which did nothing and (*xinput method*) it disabled the touch feature but didn't clear the control of the *spi* pins.

Comment: Hello & welcome to stackoverflow. please have a look on how to ask a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
I would recommend this question to be asked at the [raspberry-pi stack](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com) as this seems to have very little to do with programming.

Comment: Implement a proper authentication to the OS instead of switching off the touch device. You idea is like preventing that your bike gets stolen by taking the handlebar with you.